# How to place a border inside a grid?

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

I am using CSS grid to build a rather complex interface. I need to place a border at the end of a div between two columns. How do I do that?

The finished result has to look like this:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="expandeble">
    <div class="expID">
      <label class="idLabel">XXXX</label>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.footer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: available;
}

.expandeble {
  display: grid;
  height: 6.15vh;
  grid-template-columns: ;
  15.62vw 2.01vw 21.87vw 12.08vw 19.45vw 5.76vw 2.01vw 1.18vw 5vw 15.83vw;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(18px, 1.76vw) minmax(max-content, 3.51vh) 1.76vw;
}

.expID {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}
```

**The Border needs to have this configuration:**

```
.placeBorder {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 9;
  grid-row-start: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a pseudo-element.**

In grid layout (like in flex layout), pseudo-elements on the container are considered items. Therefore, insert a pseudo that will simulate a border across your desired grid area.

```
.expandeble::after {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 0;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 9;
  grid-row-start: 3;
}
```

[image]

```css
.expandeble {
  display: grid;
  height: 6.15vh;
  grid-template-columns: 15.62vw 2.01vw 21.87vw 12.08vw 19.45vw 5.76vw 2.01vw 1.18vw 5vw 15.83vw;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(18px, 1.76vw) minmax(max-content, 3.51vh) 1.76vw;
}

.expID {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

/* new */
.expandeble::after {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 0;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 9;
  grid-row-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="expandeble">
    <div class="expID">
      <label class="idLabel">XXXX</label>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but for others who have the same issue, here is a working example that accomplishes what you want using the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. It works even with a grid-gap.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-gap: 11px;
}
 
.cell {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Vertical lines to the left of cells in top row */
.cell:nth-child(2)::before,
.cell:nth-child(3)::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -6px;
  content: '';
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Vertical lines to the left of cells in all other rows */
.cell:nth-child(3n+5)::before,
.cell:nth-child(3n+6)::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: -6px;
  content: '';
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  height: calc(100% + 12px);
}

/* Horizontal lines above cells in first columns */
.cell:nth-child(3n+4)::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Horizontal lines above cells in all other columns */
.cell:nth-child(3n+5)::after,
.cell:nth-child(3n+6)::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -12px;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: calc(100% + 12px);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```